# a question on sum of Gaussian binomial coefficients

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, hypergeometric-functions

I was trying to calculate something and at some point I get the following sum:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{t=0,t \text{ even}}^{s}{s+3n \brack s-t}\sum_{i = 0}^{t/2}q^{2i^2}{t/2+2n-i \brack t/2-i}{n \brack 2i}x^t
\end{equation}
 can it be simplified by using a $q$-binomial identity?

Comment: How do you interpret the summands where $t$ is odd?

Comment: @Hugh Thomas,sorry i just edited the question.

Comment: The sum could only be simplified if the special case q=1 can be simplified. Do you know a simplification in this case?

Comment: @JohannCigler How can the sum be simplified if the special case q=1 can be simplified?

Comment: @rekha It's the other way: If the special case cannot be simplified then the general case also cannot.

Comment: @JohannCigler what i actually want to calculate is the following sum:\begin{equation} \sum_{t=0,t \text{ even}}^{s}q^{(s-t)(s+3)+t/2 (t+4)}{s+3 \brack s-t}{t/2 +2 \brack 2} + \sum_{t=0,t \text{ odd}}^{s}q^{(s-t)(s+3)+(t-1)/2 (t+3) +t+2}{s+3 \brack s-t}{(t-1)/2 +2 \brack 2} \end{equation}which can be simplified at q =1.